# Correlation between Bohr-model and quantum physics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics

If you're looking at the probability of finding the electron of a hydrogen atom at a distance $r$ from the nucleus, it turns out that the Bohr model for the radius of the orbit only correlates with first peak of the probability function when $\ell = n-1$. Why is that?

Comment: Because maybe, even though is insanely good for some aspects, it's a super 'crude' phenomenological model?

Answer (score 0):

When $\ell = n-1$, there are zero radial nodes and a single maxima in the radial distribution function $(4\pi r^2R^2)$.  The first peak is the only peak.